# wxPython create controls at runtime

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

i want to create a class that create control at runtime; for example:

```
self.Text1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 50,-1 ), wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB )
self.Text1.SetFont( wx.Font( 12, 74, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )
```

Tranform this (for Example define my ipotetic library) on

```
AddText(Text1, self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 50,-1 ), wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB )
self.Text1.SetFont( wx.Font( 12, 74, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )
```

It's possibible to create and accessing to control at runtime?

Thank's Aesis.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean exactly. Could you provide a more complete running example and better description?

Comment: I want to create my own function for build GUI fast.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote an article on this topic a while back which you can read here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/05/wxpython-adding-and-removing-widgets-dynamically/

The idea is to create the widget and then call the parent's Layout() method to get it to show up correctly. If you're going to be adding a lot of widgets, then you might want to use a ScrolledPanel or similar, otherwise the widgets may get added off-screen.

Binding dynamic widgets is tricky in that you want to define the event handlers BEFORE you create the widgets. I don't have any examples handy. However, you might get some ideas from this article for one approach:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

Comment: Thank's so much. I't very interesting article. I Read it.